# Swift - closure expression syntax

Tags: xcode, swift, syntax, closures, alamofire

i'm working with Alamofire library, i've noticed that they use this syntax

```
func download(method: Alamofire.Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, headers: [String : String]? = default, #destination: Alamofire.Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Alamofire.Request
```

that takes 4 parameters as input but if you go to the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading) to call the method they use the following

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100") { temporaryURL, response in
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename
    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}
return temporaryURL}
```

that takes only 2 parameters (`method:` and `URLString:`) i think that the param `headers` is optional because provide the `default` statement.
I don't understand how `Destination` is handled.
Could you please explain me how the closure is handled? 
Why the curl braces is open AFTER the method call and not inside the call after the `URLString param`?

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Marco

Comment: Have a look at ["Trailing Closures"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's the trailing closure technique

If a method accepts a closure as last param

```
class Foo {
    func doSomething(number: Int, word: String, completion: () -> ()) {

    }
}
```

You can call it following the classic way:

```
Foo().doSomething(1, word: "hello", completion: { () -> () in 
    // your code here
})
```

Or using the **trailing closure technique**:

```
Foo().doSomething(1, word: "hello") { () -> () in 
    // your code here
}
```

The result is the same, it just a more elegant (IMHO) syntax.